# Unable to connect to sybase through UFT 12.53

Tags: hp-uft

I am trying to connect UFT with Sybase. But not able to progress.
Below is the error message i got upon trying diff connection strings:

[08001][Native Code: 30012][ASEOLEDB]Client unable to establish a connection

Connection Strings

1) objConnection.open "Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise};Provider=ASEOLEDB;Data Source=ServerName/xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:PortNumber,Catalog=db;User Id=UID;Password=pwd;" (Please note string works fine when Microsoft visual basic is used to make Sybase connection.
2) objConnection.open "Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise}; Provider=ASEOLEDB;Server=sreverName/IpAdd; port=5000; db=db; uid=userid; pwd=password;"

Also i'm using DSN less connection. Ports used are - 5000, 5001, 2439, 2638, 4950

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues - No sure what worked for me will work for you but try any from my below efforts - *the ones in bold worked for me*

```
'   objConnection.Open "Provider=iAnywhere Solutions 12 - Oracle;Server =qwe.us.net.intra:1523;User Id =abc;Password=t#P2h%mUxUh;Database = SCS"

'   objConnection.Open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle;SERVER=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=qwe.us.net.intra)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=REPORTSQ.us.net.intra)));uid=abc;pwd=t#P2h%mUxUh];"

'   objConnection.Open "Driver={Microsoft ODBC Driver for Oracle};Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=REPORTINGQ.us.net.intra)(PORT=1523))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=REPORTSQ.us.net.intra)));uid=abc;pwd=t#P2h%mUxUh];"

'   objConnection.Open "Driver={Microsoft ODBC Driver for Oracle};Data Source=REPORTINGD.us.net.intra:1523;uid=abc;pwd=t#P2h%mUxUh];"

'   objConnection.Open "Provider=MSDAORA;Server =REPORTINGD.us.net.intra:1523;User Id =abc;Password=t#P2h%mUxUh];Database = SCS"

'   objConnection.Open "Driver={Microsoft ODBC for Oracle};" & "Server=REPORTINGQ.us.net.intra;" & "Uid=abc;" & "Pwd=t#P2h%mUxUh]"

'   objConnection.Open "Provider=OraOLEDB.Oracle.1;Persist Security Info=False;" & "User ID=abc;Password=t#P2h%mUxUh];Data Source=DWH_QA"

'   objConnection.Open "Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise};User ID=abc;Password=oc1b2008;Server=jdbc:sybase:Tds:scs.us.net.intra"

'   objConnection.Open "Provider=Sybase.ASEOLEDBProvider.2;User ID=abc;Password=oc1b2008;Server Name=jdbc:sybase:Tds:scs.us.net.intra,50000; Initial Catalog=s1w"

'   objConnection.Open "Provider=Sybase.ASEOLEDBProvider.2;User ID=abc;Password=oc1b2008;Data Source=jdbc:sybase:Tds:scs.us.net.intra,50000; Catalog=s1w"

'   objConnection.Open "Provider=ASEOLEDB;User ID=abc;Password=oc1b2008;Data Source=jdbc:sybase:Tds:scs.us.net.intra,50000; Catalog=s1w"

'   objConnection.Open "Provider=ASEOLEDB;User ID=abc;Password=oc1b2008;Server Name=jdbc:sybase:Tds:scs.us.net.intra,50000; Catalog=s1w"

'   objConnection.Open "Driver={Sybase ASE ODBC Driver};User ID=abc;Password=oc1b2008;NetworkAddress=jdbc:sybase:Tds:scs.us.net.intra,50000; Db=s1w"

'   objConnection.Open "Driver={Sybase ASE ODBC Driver};User ID=abc;Password=oc1b2008;NetworkAddress=jdbc:sybase:Tds:scs.us.net.intra:50000; Db=s1w"

'   objConnection.Open "Driver={Sybase ASE ODBC Driver};User ID=abc;Password=oc1b2008;NA=scs,50000; Db=s1w"

'   objConnection.Open "Driver={Sybase ASE ODBC Driver};User ID=abc;Password=oc1b2008;Srvr=jdbc:sybase:Tds:scs.us.net.intra:50000"

'   objConnection.Open "Driver={Sybase ASE ODBC Driver};User ID=abc;Password=oc1b2008;Srvr=scs.us.net.intra:50000"
```

**objConnection.Open "Driver={Adaptive Server Enterprise};User ID=abc;Password=oc1b2008;Server=scs.us.net.intra;port=50000;Db=s1w"**

**objConnection.Open "Driver={Sybase ASE ODBC Driver};User ID=abc;Password=oc1b2008;NA=scs.us.net.intra,50000; Db=s1w"**